# Dimming LED powered with an AC driver from a MCU

Tags: led, ac, switching, led-driver, triac

I want to power an LED (Forward Voltage: 30-35V, Forward Current: 50W:1750mA) with an AC driver [(link)](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33003362079.html), the title says "Dimmable", so my first question is regarding drivers, all of them will work with a dim or only the ones that say "Dimmable / TRIAC"?

Next questions are about a proper module that can do the job paired with the driver, i have seen this:
[Module 1](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32964611346.html)
[image]

and [Module 2](https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html)
[image]

Now regarding modules:

1. Module 1 says 220V, but will also be compatible with 110V? (I'm on 220V, but still like to know if is compatible)
2. Module 1 have no zero cross pin, does it handle it on hardware?
3. Both modules will work with the driver above?
4. Which module is best to go with? or other?
5. Dimming with a constant PWM rate, eg. 50% will cause any flickering to the LED light?

The PWM signal would come from an Raspberry pi and will not include effects nor smooth increments, most of the time it will be used at 0% or a fixed rate (ON/OFF) but the dimming feature is necessary to have.

Comment: 1. No 220Vmin, 2. No use ext. dimmer, 3. None have dimmer control pots, 4.1st with Triac dimmer 5. No good for your LEDs

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 So i still need an aditional piece of hardware, from what i understand i need a triac dimmer between driver and module 1? For example: https://makingcircuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/simpletriaclampdimmerswitchcircuit.png ? But replace RV1 with the output of module 1?

Comment: No .  output is the lamp or your dim able load